# Questions in the near-future tense

Tags: temps-grammatical

I know future tense and present tense-if you don’t present is:
“Je vais à la plage.”
(I am going to the beach)
And future is:
“J’irai à la plage.”
(I will go to the beach)
But how would you say ‘I am GOING to go to the beach.’ And so on?

Comment: "Je vais aller à la plage". Is that what you want?

Comment: Please check tour question, we are confusing at the end

Comment: Did I miss a subtlety between **I will go to the beach** and **I WILL go to the beach**?

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate your answers, sorry @Sharcoux, I didn’t write the question properly, my bad.

Comment: BPP's answer is the right one then.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much, BPP! That’s such a big help.

Answer (score 1):

As BPP already guessed, the closer would be:

> Je vais aller à la plage

If you want to state this future is close, you can also say, depending on how soon it's going to be:

> Je vais bientôt à la plage.
>
> Je [ne] vais pas tarder à aller à la plage.
>
> Je m'apprête à aller à la plage.
>
> Je suis sur le point d'aller à la plage.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go to the beach = je suis en train d'aller à la plage (I am on the way). On contrary, "je vais à la plage" does not imply you have gone - - example: somebody tells you "I see your car is out. Are you going somewhere?" "Yes, I go to the beach" eg. "I plan to go to the beach" (but I am still at home).